# Identifying valid fields in JointTrajectoryPoint message

Tags: ros, jointtrajectory

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When interpreting the JointTrajectoryPoint[] array provided by a JointTrajectory message, what mechanism is used to determine if optional fields (like velocities and accelerations) are valid and should be used when interpolating the path or are invalid and should be ignored?

Is it required that any unused fields are set to zero?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224404/identifying-valid-fields-in-jointtrajectorypoint-message/) by [cdsteinkuehler](https://answers.ros.org/users/25647/cdsteinkuehler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `JointTrajectoryPoint` contains individual arrays for `position`, `velocity`, `accelerations`, and  `effort`.  Array types under CPP are vector types (see [here](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Fields)).  If any of these arrays are empty (i.e. vector.empty()), then they can be considered invalid.

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2016-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cdsteinkuehler](https://answers.ros.org/users/25647/cdsteinkuehler/) on 2016-01-22**:
Thanks!  I missed the fact the variable length message arrays include a length prefix.